# Is it possible to use LightSwitch's default DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker, visual-studio-lightswitch

For developing a custom control, I'm in search of a DateTimePicker, and I could not find any useful info. LightSwitch's built-in one would be ideal for my purposes:

[image] 
[image]     [image]

Can I use this control for my own purpose? If so, how? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I could find was to create a UserControl and then place a `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker` side by side in a grid.

In the control's code-behind, declare two `DateTime` variables that hold the desired data:

```
public class MyControl
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyTime { get; set; }

    ...
```

In the control's xaml, include these namespaces:

```
xmlns:Ctls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
xmlns:ImplCtls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Implementation.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client.Internal"
```

The control's definition:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ctls:DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                         SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                         SelectedDate="{Binding Path=MyDate, ElementName=MyUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ImplCtls:BaseTimePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                 Value="{Binding Path=MyTime, ElementName=MyUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Hope this helps out someone...